# What is the correct syntax for nesting if-statements in awk?

Tags: if-statement, awk, conditional-statements

I'm writing a awk command and I would like to nest if-statements using the conditional block form:

```
condition{actions}
```

instead of the one that uses the if keyword:

```
if(condition){actions}
```

This because I'm trying to use as few characters as possible.

Using the if keyword it works:

```
awk '{system("date +%s%N")}'|awk '{t[++b]=$1;}b>1{if(b>4)e=b-5;print int(6E10*(b-e)/(t[b]-t[e+1])),"bpm"}'
```

but when I try to do with the other way:

```
awk '{system("date +%s%N")}'|awk '{t[++b]=$1;}b>1{b>4{e=b-5;}print int(6E10*(b-e)/(t[b]-t[e+1])),"bpm"}'
```

I get a syntax error:

> awk: lin. de com.:1: {b++;}b>1{b>4{e=b-5;}t[b]=$1;r=int(3E11/(t[b]-t[++e]));print r,"bpm"}
>
> awk: lin. de com.:1:(......................)^ syntax error

What would be the correct syntax?

**Edit:** the command is for calculating how many beats per minute (bpm) a user makes when he/she presses the Enter key on the keyboard.

**Input:** to hit Enter key
**Output:** how many bpm he/she did

**Example** -- If I hit the Enter key at a rate of ~ 115 bpm, the answer could be more or less like this:

> 120 bpm
>
> 112 bpm
>
> 119 bpm
>
> 122 bpm

Comment: When doing test within action block, you can not use `{b>4`, it needs to be {if(b>4) do some thing}`

Comment: Du not use system to get `date` to `awk`.  Do use some like this `awk -v date=$(date +%s%N) 'BEGIN {print date}'`

Comment: Really?! :(  My teacher told me when I asked him that it could be done, that "it 's like in C."

Comment: You can do like this: `awk  '$1>4 {print $5}'` or `awk '{if($1>4) print $5}`.  Its better you post original input text and how you like to output to be.  A nesting test `awk '{if($1>4) if($2="test) print $8}'`

Comment: The problem is not the output here. My concern here is with the number of characters that make up the command. That's why I wanted to use the block form. (It's for a challenge.)

Comment: @lleao there is a vast difference between "it can be done" and "it should be done". You CAN use shell to call awk to call system to call shell to call date as in `awk '{system("date ...")}'` but you shouldn't - just call `date ..` directly from shell instead (unless you have some specific uses cases that you don't appear to have). If you [edit] your question to provide some consiie, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you write a script to do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: Hopefully it's obvious that `condition{actions}` is **not** an "`if`-statement". You can tell because that statement doesn't have the word `if` in it.

Comment: @EdMorton my answer referred to Jotne's first comment and not the one about the system/date.

Comment: Oh then I don't see why your teacher would say "it could be done" and "it's like in C" since you can't just write `{b>4` in C either.

Comment: ok, awk it's not exactly like C, but it was inspired in C, so I think that's why he said that. He added: "In other words, you need to use curly brackets, '{...}', if the block contains more than one statement." Maybe he didn't understand my question, idk.

Comment: awk and C (and many other languages like Ada, Pascal, Java, etc.) were based on Algol. In any case, as I said - If you [edit] your question to provide some consiie, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you write a script to do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible to do something like this: condition{condition{actions}} instead of condition{if(condition)action}, but if the answer is no, okay. Thank you, guys!

Comment: We can't tell you if it's possible to do `something like this: condition{condition{actions}} instead of condition{if(condition)action}` until we know what it is you're trying to do. The answer may very well be "yes, there is something like that you can do", we just don't know until we know what the code is supposed to do by seeing an example. Also your goal seems to be to make your code briefer - there's other things could be done to your existing code to accomplish that but again, just show an example so we don't steer you wrong.

Comment: Opps, typo in my previous comment, should have been :
you can do `awk '$3>2{if ($4>5) { stuff} other stuff}` and you can do `awk '{if ($3>2) { if ($4>5)  { stuff} other stuff } something diff }'` BUT you can't do `awk '$3>2{$4>5{stuff} something else}'`.  Good luck

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I'm getting my point across in comments so ... consider this:

```
awk '{system("date +%s%N")}'
```

can be written as just:

```
date +%s%N
```

The other script:

```
{b++;}b>1{if(b>4)e=b-5;t[b]=$1;r=int(3E11/(t[b]-t[++e]));print r,"bpm"}
```

when written out legibly is:

```
{
        b++
}

b > 1 {
        if (b > 4) {
                e = b - 5
        }
        t[b] = $1
        r = int(3E11 / (t[b] - t[++e]))
        print r, "bpm"
}
```

which can then obviously be rewritten more briefly as:

```
(++b) > 4 {
        e = b - 5
}
b > 1 {
        t[b] = $1
        r = int(3E11 / (t[b] - t[++e]))
        print r, "bpm"
}
```

and from that there's no obvious reason for either `t[b]` nor `r` to exist since you can just write:

```
(++b) > 4 {
        e = b - 5
}
b > 1 {
        print int(3E11 / ($1 - t[++e])), "bpm"
}
```

and that can further be reduced to:

```
(++b) > 1 {
        e = (b > 4 ? b - 5 : e) + 1
        print int(3E11 / ($1 - t[e])), "bpm"
}
```

which you can then squeeze back into 1 line as you see fit. There's probably other ways to reduce the code but without an example to test against that's as far as Id want to guess at - there's probably already bugs introduced above by not having something to test against. Hopefully it gives you the idea of what you can do to reduce your code and why we need an example we can test against to be able to help you.